# Windows 8 Task Manager: how to enable the "CPU Time" column in the Processes tab?

Tags: windows-8, cpu-usage, task-manager

Up until Windows 7, the [Processes Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager#Processes) of the [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) would allow you to add the [CPU Time column](http://www.everytutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Task-Manager-5.jpg) (see for instance [Task Manager's possibilities you may not know](http://www.everytutorials.com/4-task-managers-possibilities-you-may-not-know/)):

> to show it, choose the`View` menu, click `Select Columns` and check the `CPU Time`.

As of the [Windows 8 Task Manager](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/27/windows-8-windows-server-2012-the-new-task-manager.aspx),

- the Select `Select Columns` menu item is gone
- the `App History` tab has a `CPU Time` column
- the `App History` tab only shows Metro style apps (not all processes)

How (apart from using non-TaskManager tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)) can I get the `CPU Time` column back in the `Processes` tab?

Comment: @Ramhound it wasnt removed. Just well hidden. Will answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 12):

You can show the *CPU time* column in the Windows 8 Task Manager, it just well hidden.

These steps and screenshots show how:

1. Start the *Task Manager*, then click on *More Details*
2. You end up in the *Processes* tab, now click on the *Details* tab
3. In the *Details* tab, you see there is no *CPU time* column, only a *CPU* column
4. *Right click* on the header of the *Details* tab, in the the pop-up menu choose *Select columns*
5. In the dialog, put a check-mark in front of *CPU time*
6. then press the *OK* button
7. Now you have the *CPU time* column in the *Details* tab

Note: If there are too many screenshots, I can link to a blog post as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to the Details tab.

Comment: Thanks. Found it per answer that @Dave gave, and used that for my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by clicking 'more details' after opening the Task Manager. Then click the 'Processes' tab. If the processor status is not any of the colums, click right at the headers and click 'Processor'.

Comment: Almost. But you got me in the right direction. I'll make an answer to explain it.